# React-js & Typescript & React-bootstrap types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

in my project I have login form, and all the elements I save in array like this:

```
const inputs: [*****] = [
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>username</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        placeholder="enter username"
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          setUsername(e.target.value)
        }
        value={username}
      ></Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>,
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>password</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        placeholder="enter password"
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          setPassword(e.target.value)
        }
        value={password}
      ></Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>,
    <Button variant="primary">Login</Button>,
  ];
```

I want to render this array with map function but I dont know what type I need to write over the **** I put up. how can  I know the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can remove the type, and then click the refactor shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>) over the variable. Once the menu pops up, click on `Infer type` (or something similar), which will automatically set the type.

However, as it is a list of components, you can try the type: `React.ReactNode[]`

> Note that Typescript arrays are not defined with `[<type-name>]`, but `<type-name>[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am using VScode and React.ReactNode works.